# When clause in listagg list

Tags: sql, oracle

I`m trying to use clause WHEN IN referring to the result from LISTAGG.

For example when: 
c = 1 and LISTAG BEBE is (1, 2, 3, 4) the code can't find common part (number 1).

```
WITH
t1 as (SELECT a, LISTAGG(b,', ') as BEBE
       FROM table1 WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY a)
       GROUP BY a)

SELECT a, c
FROM table2 t2
LEFT JOIN t1 ON t1.a = t2.a
WHERE c IN (SELECT t1.BEBE FROM t1)
```

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't work.  `LISTAGG()` returns a string that *happens* to have commas in it.  That is not the same as a list of values.

Your intentions are really unclear.  My guess is that you want something like this:

```
SELECT a, c
FROM table2 t2 
WHERE t2.c IN (SELECT t1.b FROM table1 t1 WHERE t1.a = t2.a)
```